# Django Web Form Validation

Tags: python, django, forms, web

I don't deal with web stuff much ever, which is about to become apparent.
I'm trying to add an age validator to a website I'm building - something simple, a drop down box with a yes or no.
I figured out the easiest way would be to pass the form value through an Http GET and validate it through a view.
 The GET is only passing through the "name" of the inputs in my form, for instance:

```
 <form action="/validate/" method="get">            
 <select name="validatorBox">
 <option name="yes" value="yes">
 <option name="no" value="no">
 </select>
 <input type="submit" value="I am 21 years of age or older">
```

The name "validatorBox" is being passed through, not the name of the options. Same thing with all other form input types, never values just names.
So which simple thing am I overlooking or is there a much better way to be doing this?

The view will look similar to this:

```
def search(request):
if 'yes' in request.GET:
    return render(request, 'main.html')
else:
    return render(request, 'validate.html')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how the `select` element works: it submits a single value, which is the value of the selected child option, against the name of the select itself. option elements don't actually have a name attribute.

The other problem is that `request.GET` is a dictionary, and `'foo' in dict` always checks the *keys*, not the values. You would need to actually check the value associated with the correct key:

```
if request.GET.get('validatorBox') == 'yes':
```

Finally, you probably want to check out [Django's forms framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/), rather than doing all this manually.

Comment: brilliant, thank you. I knew it was something boneheaded that I was missing.